# Error when trying to switch Polymer element to new install

Tags: polymer

I was creating a customer element using the "Your first Polymer App" templates and I wanted to switch over from the included `components` folder to a Bower managed install.  However, after swapping some URLs I began to receive the following error:

```
polymer Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to change ALL of the file paths over to the Bower install of Polymer at the same time.  HTML imports suppress duplicate paths but switching will cause it to load Polymer twice and things break.

Comment: Yes, Polymer.js can only be loaded once. If you have imports to point at some-server.com/polymer.html and localhost/polymer.html, HTML Imports can't tell that these are different files, so it loads both and things break.

Comment: @robdodson thanks for the info. JQuery and other libraries usually check if something has already grabbed '$', perhaps Polymer should check this as well?

Comment: It's a purposeful decision to make Polymer blow up in this case. Because imports can load other imports, you don't want to end up in a situation where you're expecting component-a at v1.0 and you get component-a at v2.0